# Update Entity without affecting its Navigation Property

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

in .net core 3.1

if i has a model class that has a navigation property inside of it,

```
public class Department
{
   public int ID { get;set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
   public int ID { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

According to the models before what is the difference between `.AsNoTracking()` and with tracking related to the Navigation Property

***For Example***
if i retrieve object of Department with no tracking will it populate the Student list or not and the same for `withTracking`

and another thing is

if i want to update the Department without affecting the Student list inside of it, how should i achieve that.

and last this because i have been through the ***docs*** without understanding

what `EntityState.Detached` means

and the difference between `DBSet.Attach()` and `DBSet.Update()`

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly good article that describes the behavior of tracking here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking.

As for Detach/Attach you can use the following as a guide. The example will provide some commentary around its usage.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach?view=netframework-4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1

As for updating without affecting the students what I usually do is make sure that I use the `.Include(x=> x.Students)` then perform the update on the entity object I am interested in and save those changes to the context.

Lastly there is a fantastic book that you can also read called Entity Framework Core in action. I found it very helpful when starting out with EF.

Hope this helps. Good Luck.

Comment: i've read that article taking about tracking but it dosn't speak about retrieving navigation list inside the object

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is accomplished through the "context.Departments.Include(x=> Students)"

Comment: Otherwise I am not aware of how to query the Navigation properties directly. Is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: i think ```.include``` is to populate the navigation property inside not tracked object, but what i am taking about is updating the Department itself. the update method is done with out get to include the students first then update the department, each operation done separate from the other... thanks for the book by the way

Comment: Yeah i understand what you are doing now. I would just query the Department and make sure to include the navigation objects so that you don't overwrite the list of students with a null object. At least that is how i have been doing it. There may be a better way to just update the Department without making changes to the Student child entities.